# How to hide a TemplateField column in a GridView

Tags: asp.net, .net, data-binding, gridview, exception

How can I hide a TemplateField column in a GridView?

I tried the following:

```
<asp:TemplateField ShowHeader="False" Visible='<%# MyBoolProperty %>' >
<ItemTemplate>
    <asp:LinkButton ID="attachmentButton" runat="server" ... />
</ItemTemplate>
```

but it didn't work and gives the following error:

> Databinding expressions are only supported on objects that have a DataBinding event. 
>       System.Web.UI.WebControls.TemplateField does not have a DataBinding event.

I tried also to hide it programmatically, but seems it's not possible to get a column by the name because there iss no name for `TemplateField` column.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

```
protected void OnRowCreated(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
         e.Row.Cells[columnIndex].Visible = false;
}
```

---

If you don't prefer hard-coded index, the only workaround I can suggest is to **provide a `HeaderText` for the `GridViewColumn` and then find the column using that `HeaderText`**.

```
protected void UsersGrid_RowCreated(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    ((DataControlField)UsersGrid.Columns
            .Cast<DataControlField>()
            .Where(fld => fld.HeaderText == "Email")
            .SingleOrDefault()).Visible = false;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I wonder how can I get its index, I don't prefer the hard-coded indexes.

Comment: @naveen e.Row.Cells[columnIndex].Visible = false; hides column data perfectly.... What if i also want to hide corresponding Header Template??

Comment: @Gk_999: It hides the header template too

Comment: @naveen
your solution with DataControlField works also after databind the only advise is to put the title of column in this way:
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText ="Email">

Comment: What if the HeaderText is localized?

Comment: @A-Sharabiani: been a while. Will check when I get time

Comment: Doing it on OnDataBound event will only run it once instead of once per row. This may be prefer if the function is heavy.

Answer (score 10):

```
For Each dcfColumn As DataControlField In gvGridview.Columns
    If dcfColumn.HeaderText = "ColumnHeaderText" Then
        dcfColumn.Visible = false                    
    End If
Next
```

Answer (score 10):

If appears to me that rows where Visible is set to false won't be accessible, that they are removed from the DOM rather than hidden, so I also used the Display: None approach. In my case, I wanted to have a hidden column that contained the key of the Row. To me, this declarative approach is a little cleaner than some of the other approaches that use code.

```
<style>
   .HiddenCol{display:none;}                
</style>


 <%--ROW ID--%>
      <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Row ID">
       <HeaderStyle CssClass="HiddenCol" />
       <ItemTemplate>
       <asp:Label ID="lblROW_ID" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("ROW_ID") %>'></asp:Label>
       </ItemTemplate>
       <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Right" CssClass="HiddenCol" />
       <EditItemTemplate>
       <asp:TextBox ID="txtROW_ID" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("ROW_ID") %>'></asp:TextBox>
       </EditItemTemplate>
       <FooterStyle CssClass="HiddenCol" />
      </asp:TemplateField>
```

Answer (score 7):

```
GridView1.Columns[columnIndex].Visible = false;
```

Answer (score 4):

try this

```
.hiddencol
    {
        display:none;
    }
    .viscol
    {
        display:block;
    }
```

add following code on RowCreated Event of GridView

```
protected void OnRowCreated(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
     if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
     {
         e.Row.Cells[0].CssClass = "hiddencol";
     }
     else if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Header)
     {
         e.Row.Cells[0].CssClass = "hiddencol";
     }
}
```

Comment: this is fine if all you care about is the visibility on the screen, however if you are showing/hiding private information (IE stackoverflow real name) then you cannot just hide it on the client, it can't be sent to the client at all

Answer (score 2):

Am I missing something ?

If you can't set visibility on TemplateField then set it on its content

```
<asp:TemplateField>
  <ItemTemplate>
    <asp:LinkButton Visible='<%# MyBoolProperty %>' ID="foo" runat="server" ... />
  </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

or if your content is complex then enclose it into a div and set visibility on the div

```
<asp:TemplateField>
  <ItemTemplate>
    <div runat="server" visible='<%# MyBoolProperty  %>' >
      <asp:LinkButton ID="attachmentButton" runat="server" ... />
    </div>
  </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Comment: Problem with that is that you cannot place a <div> outside of a template field.

Comment: Seemed quite obvious to me that the div was inside the templatefield. Anyway I edited to make it more obvious than obvious

Answer (score 1):

```
protected void gvLogMessageDetail_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)  
    { 
      if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Header)   
        {  
            if (rdlForImportOrExport.SelectedIndex == 1)  
            {  
                e.Row.Cells[3].Visible = false;  
                e.Row.Cells[4].Visible = false;  
                e.Row.Cells[5].Visible = false;  
            }  
            else  
            {  
                e.Row.Cells[3].Visible = true;  
                e.Row.Cells[4].Visible = true;  
                e.Row.Cells[5].Visible = true;  
            }  
        }    
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow) //skip header row  
        {  
            try  
            {  
                if (rdlForImportOrExport.SelectedIndex == 1)  
                {  
                    e.Row.Cells[3].Visible = false;  
                    e.Row.Cells[4].Visible = false;  
                    e.Row.Cells[5].Visible = false;  
                }  
                else  
                {  
                    e.Row.Cells[3].Visible = true;  
                    e.Row.Cells[4].Visible = true;  
                    e.Row.Cells[5].Visible = true;  
                }  
                }  
            catch  
            {  
                ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), "Expand", "<SCRIPT   LANGUAGE='javascript'>alert('There is binding problem in child grid.');</script>");  
            }  
        }  
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

A *slight* improvement using column name, IMHO:

```
    Private Sub GridView1_Init(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles GridView1.Init
    For Each dcf As DataControlField In GridView1.Columns
        Select Case dcf.HeaderText.ToUpper
            Case "CBSELECT"
                dcf.Visible = Me.CheckBoxVisible
                dcf.HeaderText = "<small>Select</small>"
        End Select
    Next
End Sub
```

This allows control over multiple column.
I initially use a 'technical' column name, matching the control name within.
This makes it obvious within the ASCX page that it's a control column.
Then swap out the name as desired for presentation.
If I spy the odd name in production, I know I skipped something.
The "ToUpper" avoids case-issues.

Finally, this runs ONE time on any post instead of capturing the event during row-creation.

Answer (score 0):

This can be another way to do it and validate nulls

```
DataControlField dataControlField = UsersGrid.Columns.Cast<DataControlField>().SingleOrDefault(x => x.HeaderText == "Email");
            if (dataControlField != null)
                dataControlField.Visible = false;
```