# How to hide gridview column after databind?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, sqldatasource

I hide my columns using the solution in following link

[How to hide a TemplateField column in a GridView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4954871/how-to-hide-a-templatefield-column-in-a-gridview)

However this causes problems with update operations, as gridview acts as hidden rows has null value. So how to hide columns after databind?

```
protected void begv_OrderDetail_RowCreated(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    ((DataControlField)begv_OrderDetail.Columns.Cast<DataControlField>().Where(fld => fld.HeaderText == "FileNo").SingleOrDefault()).Visible = "False";
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this,

```
grid1.Columns[columnIndex].Visible= false;
```

*Edit based on comment of questioner, for getting values of hidden columns*

You can use hidden fields to store column wise values. This [**article**](http://geekswithblogs.net/dotNETvinz/archive/2009/06/22/faq-how-to-get-hidden-columns-value-in-gridview.aspx) has example that will help how to use hidden fields.

Instead of hiding column you can put the data of columns in datakeynames and later access those values. This will be useful in grabbing how to use **[DataKeyNames](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/23833/DataKeyNames)**. By this method you may need to pass the id from data key names and get the record.

Comment: this does not work. I manually put some value to database for Gridview. When my column is hidden, update button updates this value with null. When column is not hidden, the default value remains as it is after update button.(what is the  difference of this then mine?, aren't they same?)

Comment: Instead of hiding column you can put the data of columns in datakeynames and later access those values. This will be useful in grabbing the concept. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/23833/DataKeyNames

Comment: Thank you much, Adding the hidden column's data value to datakeynames solved my problem.

Comment: problem was not updating when row is hidden, this time, when hidden row is visible, it does not update the value since it is using the datakeyname as its parameter and keeps the current value

Answer (score 0):

try this example, (i don't speak english)

into RowDataBound ...

```
 protected void gvTeste_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            teste listaTeste = e.Row.DataItem as ListaTeste;

            if (listaTeste.ID == 0)
            {
                e.Row.Cells[2].Text = "Não Atribuido";
            }

            if (e.Row.Cells[7].Text == "01/01/0001" || e.Row.Cells[8].Text == "01/01/0001")
            {
                **e.Row.Visible = false;** // disable row
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: he wants column to be hidden not row!