# how to hide datatable column from gridview in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, gridview, datatable

I want to hide column in gridview. I create a datatable and add data in it from database then bind it with gridview. And now i want to hide 0 index column form it but it is not hiding.
Please help me.

This is my Code.

`int companyID = Convert.ToInt16(Session["companyID"]);

```
            DataTable taskTable = new DataTable("TaskList");

            SqlConnection sql_connection = new SqlConnection("data source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=SSPI; initial catalog=db_ease");
            SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand("select tbl_employee.empID,tbl_employee.empEmploymentID,tbl_employee.empFirstname,tbl_employee.empMiddlename,tbl_employee.empLastname,tbl_employee.empGender,tbl_employee.empMobileNo,tbl_employee.empMac,tbl_association.associationStatus from tbl_employee inner join tbl_association on tbl_employee.empID=tbl_association.empID where tbl_association.companyID="+companyID, sql_connection);
            SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlCommand);

            adapter.Fill(taskTable);
            Session["TaskTable"] = taskTable;

            taskTable.Columns[0].ColumnName = "Employee ID";
            taskTable.Columns[1].ColumnName = "Employment ID";
            taskTable.Columns[2].ColumnName = "First Name";
            taskTable.Columns[3].ColumnName = "Middle Name";
            taskTable.Columns[4].ColumnName = "Last Name";
            taskTable.Columns[5].ColumnName = "Gender";
            taskTable.Columns[6].ColumnName = "Mobile No";
            taskTable.Columns[7].ColumnName = "MAC Address";
            taskTable.Columns[8].ColumnName = "Status";


            BindData();
            displayGridView.Columns[0].Visible = false;
            sql_connection.Close();`
```

This is my gridview

`<asp:GridView ID="displayGridView" runat="server" 
                        CssClass="table table-striped table-bordered dataTable"
                        OnRowEditing="displayGridView_RowEditing" 
                        OnRowUpdating="displayGridView_RowUpdating" 
                        OnRowDeleting="displayGridView_RowDeleting"
                        OnRowCancelingEdit="displayGridView_RowCancelingEdit" 
                        AllowPaging="true" OnPageIndexChanging="displayGridView_PageIndexChanging" 
                        OnSorting="displayGridView_RowSorting"
                        AutoGenerateDeleteButton="true" 
                        AutoGenerateEditButton="true" 
                        PagerSettings-FirstPageText="First" 
                        PagerSettings-LastPageText="Last" 
                        PagerSettings-Mode="NumericFirstLast" 
                        PagerSettings-PageButtonCount="4" PageSize="4"
                        EmptyDataText="No data found" 
                        AllowSorting="True"
                        OnDataBound="displayGridView_OnDataBound"
                        >
                        </asp:GridView>`

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to hide a TemplateField column in a GridView](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4954871/how-to-hide-a-templatefield-column-in-a-gridview)

Answer (score 0):

you should hide column on displayGridView_RowDataBound event like this.

```
   protected void displayGridView_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {

        e.Row.Cells[0].Visible = false;

    }
```

Comment: OnDataBound="GridView_RowDataBound" This event will use?

Comment: Specified argument was out of the range of valid values.
Parameter name: index "this is error come when i add this code"

Comment: if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
            {
                e.Row.Cells[0].Visible = false;
}


Try this.....

Comment: and how to hide this column header?

Answer (score 0):

When you only need some of the columns in your gridview you should add only that columns in your aspx file like below:

```
   <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" AutoGenerateColumns="false" runat="server">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Header Name" DataField="NameOfFieldInDatabase" />
        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Header Name2" DataField="NameOfFieldInDatabase2" />
        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Header Name3" DataField="NameOfFieldInDatabase3" />
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

You also should add the  AutoGenerateColumns="false" to gridview like the code above, otherwise you would have the customized columns plus all other auto generated columns