# Passing data to function

Tags: html, asp.net

I want to pass the variable Date to my function HasBtnRights(). Any suggestions on how to do that?

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="More info" Visible='<%#HasBtnRights(Eval("Date")) %>'>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Button runat="server" OnClientClick='openModalPopup(<%# Eval("Agreement")%>);' Text="Open"/>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Comment: Is `HasBtnRights` a JavaScript function, or a method in your code behind? Does your current code give you an error?

Comment: check this out... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4954871/how-to-hide-a-templatefield-column-in-a-gridview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to hide / show the button based on certain criteria, you can set the Visible property of the Button itself.

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="More info" >
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Button runat="server" Visible='<%#HasBtnRights(Eval("Date")) %>'  OnClientClick='openModalPopup(<%# Eval("Agreement")%>);' Text="Open" />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

An then, in your code behind:

```
public bool HasBtnRights(DateTime myDate) {
    // your date logic here
    return true; // or return false;
}
```