What are the GridView OnDataBound and OnPreRender events used/good for?
For context read on but, ultimately, is it possible/(and how) to update (remove/hide a column) a GridView in the OnDataBound() or OnPreRender() events?
I query data from a database and display it on a gridview. I'm using the OnRowDataBound event to format numbers, etc. In that result set I have a column named 'orderby' that I use to order the result rows. I would like to remove this column from the gridview. If I autogeneratecolumns I can hide this column in the OnRowDataBound() event by doing the following (e.Row.Cells[r].Visible = false;) on the DataControlRowType.Header and DataControlRowType.DataRow. If I don't autogenerate columns and I add Hidden="true" in the column parameters of the .aspx, it does not work. I'm not looking for a solution in the .aspx btw...
For some reason I thought that the OnDataBound() and OnPreRender() events could be used to update GridViews (hide rows, columns, create total row) but that does not seem to be the case. If I try the below it does not work (gridView.Columns.Count is 0 even though there is data). I can get the desired effect if I use the OnRowDataBound() event but I was wondering:

can the OnDataBound() and OnPreRender() events update a gridview? If so pls point me to an example.
what can you do with the OnDataBound() and OnPreRender()/what are they good for? I haven't really used them before and, again, I thought that they would be able to help with last minute updates/touchups on grid views.

Note: The OnRowDataBound() method is doing updates row by row, column by column. With a complicated page you can easily have some nasty long code. So I would imagine that once all of that is sorted out there would be a way to 'easily' hide a column for example; but I could be wrong...
btw I'm running:

.Net version: 4.0.30319.42000
runtimeVer: .NET Framework 4.8.4645.0

    protected void checks_DataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        GridView gridView = (GridView)sender;
        if (gridView.ClientID == "checks_db_sod01")
        {
            for (int c = 0; c < gridView.Columns.Count; c++)
            {
                if (gridView.Columns[c].HeaderText.ToLower().Trim() == "orderby")
                {
                    gridView.Columns[c].Visible = false;
                }
            }
        }
    }


You should probably stick to one question per post but, to address your specific queries:

Yes, OnDataBound() and OnPreRender() can update certain aspects of the GridView such as data formatting or applying styles. They're not used for structural changes like removing columns; for that, you'd typically manipulate the GridView's properties directly or handle such tasks during the GridView's initialization or data binding phases.
These events are for used for formatting, applying styles, calculating totals, etc. Think of it as post-processing.

You could possibly use PreRender to hide your column though. Note that it's been about 5 years since I used web forms, but this might get you started:
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        // Initialize or bind your GridView here.
        // You can manipulate GridView columns before or after binding.
    }
}

protected void checks_DataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // You can perform final adjustments to the GridView after data binding.
    // This could include formatting, styling, calculations...
}

protected void checks_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var gridView = (GridView)sender;
    if (gridView.ClientID == "checks_db_sod01")
    {
        // Iterate through columns and hide the one with header text "orderby".
        foreach (DataControlField column in gridView.Columns)
        {
            if (column.HeaderText.ToLower().Trim() == "orderby")
            {
                column.Visible = false;
            }
        }
    }
}

Hope this helps!

Tyvm. Using the code that you provided and using the watch to make sure that checks_PreRender() is running on the corresponding gridView, I see that 'gridView.Columns' has a Count = 0. So nothing happens in the foreach. I can do everything in OnRowDataBound() but it appears that OnDataBound and OnPreRender simply do not have access to the gridView contents/they are empty. Not sure what is going on. I've tried all kinds of ways...

protected void checks_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)     {         var gridView = (GridView)sender;         if (gridView.ClientID == "checks_db_px01")         {             gridView.Rows[2].Visible = false;         }     }
The code above deleted a row. Now I'm searching for any way to remove/hide a column.

Honestly, your best bet is probably to manipulate the data before you data bind the GridView. Pull it down from the database and then build a new DataTable from the data and exclude the column there.

SOLUTION
Thanks to Ortund and Rand Random I tried a few things. To be clear, Ortund's reply used gridView.Columns and for some reason, in OnPreRender my gridView had 3 rows and 0 columns. Without OnPreRender() the gridView whould display 4 rows (1 header, 3 data rows) and 3 columns.
What finally worked is posted below. Note that the solution is iterating through header rows and columns (O(N)) which is OK I guess. Also, if I don't explicitly hide the corresponding headerCell I still get the column but without data. If anyone has another solution, hopefully a faster/more efficient one, that would be most appreciated! Thank you again for those who responded. If anyone has any resource on how to properly do cool things with GridViews pls post it. I'm usually hacking away updates/changes in the OnRowDataBound() method only...
    protected void checks_PreRender01(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var gridView = (GridView)sender;
        if (gridView.ClientID == "checks_db_px01")
        {
            int targetColumnIndex = -1;
            if (gridView.HeaderRow != null)
            {
                foreach (TableCell headerCell in gridView.HeaderRow.Cells)
                {
                    if (headerCell.Text.ToLower().Trim() == "orderby")
                    {
                        headerCell.Visible = false;
                        targetColumnIndex = gridView.HeaderRow.Cells.GetCellIndex(headerCell);
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            if (targetColumnIndex != -1)
            {
                foreach (GridViewRow row in gridView.Rows)
                {
                    row.Cells[targetColumnIndex].Visible = false;
                }
            }

        }
    }


You could use the RowCreated Event of the GridView and some LINQ to achieve this
protected void checks_RowCreated(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    GridView gridView = (GridView)sender;
    if (gridView.ClientID == "checks_db_sod01")
    {
        ((DataControlField)gridView.Columns
            .Cast<DataControlField>()
            .Where(fld => fld.HeaderText.ToLower().Trim() == "orderby")
            .SingleOrDefault()).Visible = false;
    }
}



would the RowCreated event actually post back to the server for every row? seems a lot of post backs if done for each row

should hit for each row in a loop. Will there be a postback back for each row? No

@RandRandom: this worked 13 years back with web forms. https://stackoverflow.com/a/4954976/17447 my own answer. haven't been using it for so long.


in that result set I have a column named 'orderby' that I use to order the result rows. I would like to remove this column from the GridView.

Then don't include the column in the resulting query. You can ALWAYS use an order by clause, and that order by clause does not require the column to be included in the resulting query.
e.g.:
 SELECT ID, HotelName FROM tblHotels ORDER BY City

So, in above note how the order by clause is not included in the columns output, and as such, no requirement exists to do so.

I add Hidden="true"

I never seen that work, nor ever used.
You can use style="display:none", if you want that markup to be rendered client side if you want such markup to render in the client-side markup, but not display. This is important if you have some client-side JavaScript that still needs to use the value, but it not displays.
Or you can use (better) simply visible=false. This will also hide the markup in question but also does NOT send the markup to the client side. In other words, visible=false not only hides the markup, but also does not send nor render such markup to the browser (and thus such markup is not available to client-side JavaScript).
Hence, depending on if you require client-side JavaScript to use that hidden column or not, then visible=false is a far better choice.
So, you can most certainly (and should) still use the Row data bound event.
However, you can of course simply change the markup if you not used autogenerated columns.
Here is a working example, and in this case, we have a button on the form to hide the column.
Hence, this markup:
        <asp:Button ID="cmdHide" runat="server" Text="Hide Active column"
            OnClick="cmdHide_Click" CssClass="btn"
            />

        <asp:GridView ID="GVHotels" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
            DataKeyNames="ID" CssClass="table table-hover"
            OnRowDataBound="GVHotels_RowDataBound">
            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="FirstName" HeaderText="FirstName" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="LastName" HeaderText="LastName" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="City" HeaderText="City" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="HotelName" HeaderText="HotelName" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Description" HeaderText="Description" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Active" HeaderText="Active"  />
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>

And our code behind is this:
    bool HideActive = false;
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
            LoadGrid();
    }

    void LoadGrid()
    {
        string strSQL =
            "SELECT * FROM tblHotelsA ORDER BY HotelName";
        GVHotels.DataSource = General.MyRst(strSQL);
        GVHotels.DataBind();    

    }

    protected void GVHotels_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow
            | e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Header
            | e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Footer) {

            if (HideActive)
            {
                e.Row.Cells[5].Visible = false;
            }
        }
    }

    protected void cmdHide_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        HideActive = true;
        LoadGrid();
    }

And the result is this:

So, in summary:
You don't have to include the column for an order by clause in the output.
You can (and should) continue to use the row data bound event.
You as a developer will make the choice between visible="false", or using style="display:none" depending on if you need that column for use by client-side JavaScript code.
So, row data bound can hide the column, but you have to hide the header column, the footer column, and the data column for this to work.

Thank you very much. This is very useful. I had not yet considered the client side Js...
